# Fast splitting of array on column indices from each row of sparse array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

Let's say I have a sparse array and a dense array that has the same number of columns but fewer rows:

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
import numpy as np

sp_arr = csr_matrix(np.array([[1,0,0,0,1],[0,0,1,0,0],[0,1,0,0,1],[0,0,0,1,1],[0,0,0,1,0]]))
arr = np.random.rand(10).reshape(2,5)
print(arr)
[[ 0.47027789  0.82510323  0.01321617  0.66264852  0.3618022 ]
 [ 0.80198907  0.36350616  0.10254934  0.65209401  0.094961  ]]
```

I would like to get an array containing all of the submatrices for the indices that contain values for each row of the sparse array. For example, the indices for data in `sp_arr` are as follows:

0: [0, 4]
1: [2]
2: [1, 4]
3: [3, 4]
4: [3]

My output should look like this:

```
array([array([[ 0.47027789,  0.3618022 ],
       [ 0.80198907,  0.094961  ]]),
       array([[ 0.01321617],
       [ 0.10254934]]),
       array([[ 0.82510323,  0.3618022 ],
       [ 0.36350616,  0.094961  ]]),
       array([[ 0.66264852,  0.3618022 ],
       [ 0.65209401,  0.094961  ]]),
       array([[ 0.66264852],
       [ 0.65209401]])], dtype=object)
```

I can create this with the following code, but as the size of the arrays scale up (greatly in my case) it gets really slow.

```
output = np.empty(sp_arr.shape[0], dtype=object)
for row in range(sp_arr.shape[0]):
    output[row] = arr[:, sp_arr[row].indices]
```

I've thought about vectorizing the process and applying it along the axis, but `np.apply_along_axis` doesn't work with sparse matrices, and unfortunately while this example is small enough to make dense and then use `apply_along_axis` my actual sparse matrix is much too large to do so (>100Gb).

I had thought that perhaps there is a fancy way to index or use something like hsplit to accomplish this with already vectorized methods, but so far I haven't had any luck. Is there someway to achieve this that is just escaping me?

**Update**

Per the answer from @Divakar, which is great, I found another way to implement the same thing with the ever so slightest, and negligible, improvement.

@Divakars best answer was:

```
def app2(sp_arr, arr):
    r,c = sp_arr.nonzero()
    idx = np.flatnonzero(r[1:] > r[:-1])+1    
    idx0 = np.concatenate(( [0] , idx, [r.size] ))
    arr_c = arr[:,c]
    return [arr_c[:,i:j] for i,j in zip(idx0[:-1], idx0[1:])]
```

Which increased my performance by 50 - 60x! But its kind of hard to read.

What I discovered is that given the csr_matrix format you can use the `indices` and `indptr` attributes to your advantage here.

```
def final_app():
    idx = sp_arr.indptr
    arr_c = arr[:, sp_arr.indices]
    out = [arr_c[:, i:j] for i, j in zip(idx[:-1], idx[1:])]
    return out
```

In the end the performance is statistically the same (less than 50ms improvement on a sparse matrix 276538 x 33114), but it feels easier to understand. **More Importantly** this approach does include the rows for which there are no values at all, whereas the previous approach does not. This may seem unimportant, but for my use case it is pretty critical.

**Update 2**

In response to @EelcoHoogendoorn. The problem is part of a parallel implementation of the alternative least squares with regularization method that I am trying to implement in python. This comes from the oft cited paper [Large-scale Parallel Collaborative Filtering for
the Netflix Prize](https://endymecy.gitbooks.io/spark-ml-source-analysis/content/%E6%8E%A8%E8%8D%90/papers/Large-scale%20Parallel%20Collaborative%20Filtering%20the%20Netflix%20Prize.pdf) The normal way of doing this is by having distributed copies of the Ratings, User, and Items matrices across processes. I thought it might be interesting to see what would happen if we constructed all of the item submatrices up front and just distributed those to the processes. That way the processes need only return the feature columns for either one user or one item respectively and those could be used to update the User and Item matrices.

The above problem was actually the bottleneck in my current implementation. And per your comment, in this situation I don't believe the transposition is critical as part of the algorithm takes the dot product of each submatrix with its transpose.

Comment: `apply_along_axis` does not 'vectorize' in the true numpy sense of the word.  It just hides the iteration over all other axes.

Comment: In reply to your update2; I am bearish on the prospects of splitting sparse matrix multiplication over multiple processes in python. The compute intensity of a single block of matrix-vector multiplication is quite low compared to the communication overhead you will find yourself with given pythons' multiprocessing limitations. I thought perhaps dask (https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/2160) might help you but it does not look like it. Lots of good discussion on the subject there though.

Comment: @EelcoHoogendoorn I totally agree with your intuition, the communication overhead takes up the majority of the computation time, but I would posit that there is an inflection point where the parallel method becomes viable as the size of the matrix increases. My given ratings matrix is ~270K x 33K and with the parallel implementation it takes less than 1 minute while the loop takes over 18 minutes. Obviously the time will be a factor of rank and matrix size so its tough to tell but I would feel confident saying that for larger matrices the parallel method will perform better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are two options - `np.split` or `loop comprehension`. In my experience, I have found out the latter to be faster. But, the priority must be to do minimal work inside the loop comprehension by doing as much of pre-processing as possible.

**Approach #1 :** First approach using `np.split` -

```
# Get row, col indices
r,c = sp_arr.nonzero()

# Get intervaled indices for row indices. 
# We need to use these to cut the column indexed input array.
idx = np.flatnonzero(r[1:] > r[:-1])+1
out = np.split(arr[:,c], idx, axis=1)
```

Sample output -

```
In [56]: [i.tolist() for i in out]
Out[56]: 
[[[0.47027789, 0.3618022], [0.80198907, 0.094961]],
 [[0.01321617], [0.10254934]],
 [[0.82510323, 0.3618022], [0.36350616, 0.094961]],
 [[0.66264852, 0.3618022], [0.65209401, 0.094961]],
 [[0.66264852], [0.65209401]]]
```

**Approach #2 :** The second one and should be better on performance and we will re-use `r,c,idx` from previous method -

```
idx0 = np.concatenate(( [0] , idx, [r.size] ))
arr_c = arr[:,c]
out = [arr_c[:,i:j] for i,j in zip(idx0[:-1], idx0[1:])]
```

See, the `loop-comprehension` simply slices the array of already indexed array `arr_c`. That's as minimal as one could get and as such should be good.

**Runtime test**

Approaches -

```
def org_app(sp_arr, arr):
    output = np.empty(sp_arr.shape[0], dtype=object)
    for row in range(sp_arr.shape[0]):
        output[row] = arr[:, sp_arr[row].indices]
    return output

def app1(sp_arr, arr):
    r,c = sp_arr.nonzero()
    idx = np.flatnonzero(r[1:] > r[:-1])+1
    return np.split(arr[:,c], idx, axis=1)

def app2(sp_arr, arr):
    r,c = sp_arr.nonzero()
    idx = np.flatnonzero(r[1:] > r[:-1])+1    
    idx0 = np.concatenate(( [0] , idx, [r.size] ))
    arr_c = arr[:,c]
    return [arr_c[:,i:j] for i,j in zip(idx0[:-1], idx0[1:])]
```

Timings -

```
In [146]: sp_arr = csr_matrix((np.random.rand(100000,100)>0.8).astype(int))
     ...: arr = np.random.rand(10,sp_arr.shape[1])
     ...: 

In [147]: %timeit org_app(sp_arr, arr)
     ...: %timeit app1(sp_arr, arr)
     ...: %timeit app2(sp_arr, arr)
     ...: 
1 loops, best of 3: 5.66 s per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 146 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 105 ms per loop
```

Comment: Nice! Still trying to wrap my brain around these, but I think I follow. Just for reference on my data this took the computation from 18 s to 302ms!

Comment: @Grr Nice speedup there! Well, the codes in this proposed methods use slicing at different places, which being views are just like godsend in NumPy being very efficient. Methodically speaking, we are just getting the start and stop indices after lining up all the valid columns as one big wide array version : `arr_c` in the second method.

Comment: Check out my updated question. I discovered that you can use the attributes of the sparse matrix to access the same values you are calculating for index and columns, which is kinda cool.

Comment: @Grr Very kool find there! Seems like a perfect case to use `indptr`. That's the best way to go by finding solutions on your own and even better to improve upon existing ones. Good job!

Answer (score 1):

The [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author), allows you to do things like this using a simple one-liner:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
r, c = sp_arr.nonzero()
s = group_by(r).split(arr.T[c])
```

Performance should be similar to the currently accepted answer, though marginally slower. Note that the elements of s now come out transposed relative to your original layout, so if this is a hard interface requirement, another pass will be required.

Aside from being more concise and testable the reason I bring up this approach is that it is quite likely that a more elegant solution could be found still, if you describe your problem at a slightly higher level, rather than the subproblem you presented us with. In my experience, a splitting operation is rarely the end result of anything, so if subsequent operations are required, this might reveal even more opportunities to express your logic at a higher level of abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use `groupby`.

```
from itertools import groupby

rows, cols = sp_arr.nonzero()
out = [arr[:, [g[1] for g in group]] for _, group in groupby(zip(rows, cols), lambda x: x[0])]
```